# Firefox writing session.rdf every two seconds

Tags: linux, firefox

Firefox (version 23 under Linux) sometimes gets into writing 
  <profile>/session.rdf every two seconds, whether it has changed or not.

Any idea why this happens and how I can stop it from doing that?

Some observations (either clues or red herrings):

- Seems to happen only after the Firefox has been running for a few days. 
  (not sure about this)
- Often the only difference is the ordering of lines such as:
  <RDF:li RDF:resource="rdf://tabmix/closed0/window/M1o23rTw"/>
  (Note that I use the Tab Mix Plus extension.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the Tab Mix Plus session manager, you **can't change** the fixed interval of 2 seconds. On the other hand, if you've chosen the Firefox built-in session manager, you can change the interval between saving operations like this:

Got to the `about:config` page and search for `browser.sessionstore.interval`.

This value should be a positive integer indicating the number of milliseconds between session saving operations and defaults to 15000, i. e. 15 seconds.

Comment: Thanks! - But setting the interval was easier than you described.
When I changed the manager choice in the TabMixPlus preferences, 
it automatically presented a field for setting the minimum interval as
an Advanced ("if you know what you're doing") Setting.

Comment: I didn't know about that but then I haven't used TMP for quite a while. Good to know, though.